# How to find all Person Account records with a-z/A-Z characters in the phone number fields

Tags: reporting, data

**Background**

The telephone number fields like `mobile phone` and `home phone` on the `Person Account` object contain descriptive words in like:

> 07970 123 123 (dad mobile)

**Question**

How could I get a list/report of all records with the invalid characters in these fields?

Comment: I was going to suggest creating a custom formula field with the REGEX function, but unfortunately REGEX is not available in formula fields, only for validation rules and workflow rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of functions that can do this in SOQL. The quick solution may be to write a simple Apex, extract phone numbers, compare using ASCII values, and output defaulters.

Something like -

```
Pattern numPattern = Pattern.compile('[0-9]{10}');  // not for your use case! I am weak in REGEX :)
Matcher phMatcher = numPattern.matcher(sPhone);  

if(!phMatcher.matches()){
    invalidList.add(sPhone);
}

System.debug('Invalid list: ' + invalidList);
```